# Get form names in windev

Tags: acrofields, windev

I use Itextsharp in WinDev and I try to get the names of a form.
My code is hereafter :

Machaine est une chaine

```
PdfSource= FicSource
PdfDestination = RepCible+"\"+fExtraitChemin(PdfSource,fFichier)+" "+CodId+".pdf"
MonStream = allouer un FileStream(PdfDestination,FileMode::Create)
```

MonPdfReader est un PdfReader(PdfSource)

```
POUR TOUT MaChaine  DANS MonPdfReader.AcroFields.Fields.Keys
```

FIN

The problem is that 
"MonPdfReader.AcroFields.Fields.Keys"
is not accepted.

Thanks for your ideas ...

Comment: Please try to explain a more detailed what you want to do. The french sentences are belonging to the code or not? Please adjust it. :)

Comment: Ok.My aim is to get the fields names so that i can more easyly fill them

Comment: The french sentences are part of the code.
I do not succeed in defining the collection which is iterated.

Comment: In my code, "MaChaine" is a string and WinDev/Itext doesn't accept a string to refer to field.keys.

Comment: I eventually found out what was wrong.
If anybody interested :
PdfSource= Sai_FicSource //file pdf source
MonPdfReader est un PdfReader(PdfSource)
Monfield est un AcroFields.Item

POUR TOUT Monfield DE MonPdfReader.AcroFields.Fields.Keys
 MaChaine=Monfield
FIN

Comment: If this is your solution, please answer your own question. :)

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't answer your question, here it is :

```
PdfSource = Sai_FicSource 
//file pdf source 
MonPdfReader est un PdfReader(PdfSource) 
Monfield est un AcroFields.Item 
POUR TOUT Monfield DE MonPdfReader.AcroFields.Fields.Keys 
    MaChaine = Monfield 
FIN
```